# What is the Alt+code for Parallelism(Geometric) symbol

Tags: tesseract

I want Parallelism altcode shortcut please anyone help me.I have to traine those symbol in tesseract

Comment: Do you mean Shift and | ( key with the \ symbol.)?

Comment: " // "  This symol . Like example is CYLINDRICITY(U+232D)@ Mark

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about ║ symbol (U+2551)

[More info about this symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2551/index.htm)

```
How to type in Microsoft Windows    Alt +2551
                                    Alt 186
```

You can find List of Unicode Characters of Category “Other Symbol” [HERE](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/So?page=1)